# circle vs circle sweep test that returns touch point

Tags: language-agnostic, geometry, collision-detection, collision

I'm looking for an algorithm that takes two dynamic circles and returns point of contact. For some reason when trying to search for this I can only find resources like: http://ericleong.me/research/circle-circle/ which describe algorithms that return resulting velocities.

Comment: This seems like something very basic so I'm probably just missing something, or I am looking it up under the wrong name. Rip the karma i'll loose when this is marked duplicate :(

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined problem well.

Let circles centers are moving with equations

```
cx1 = cx1_0 + t * vx1
cx2 = cx2_0 + t * vx2
cy1 = cy1_0 + t * vy1
cy2 = cy2_0 + t * vy2
```

where cx1_0 is starting X-coordinate of the first circle, vx1 is x-component of its velocity.

Circles touch each other when center-center distance is equal to the sum of radii. We can use squared values:

```
(cx1 - cx2)^2 + (cy1 - cy2)^2 = (r1 + r2)^2
```

Substitute expressions above, open parentheses, solve quadratic equation for unknown parameter t. You can get 0, 1 or two solutions (no interaction, one touching, intersection period exists). Then calculate centers coordinates for moment of touch  and get touch point for **external** touching:

```
x_touch = (cx1 * r1 + cx2 * r2) / (r1 + r2)
similar for y
```

Note that I emphasize external because internal touching might occur (in that case distance is equal to the difference of radii, but I think such case is not interesting for you)